# Angular4 Testing Karma - Error: Can't resolve all parameters for RequestOptions: (?)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

This is my spec.ts file. I'm stuck with the error:

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for RequestOptions: (?)

I have imported all the providers necessary also. Can anyone please help me resolve this error?

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ResetPasswordComponent } from './reset-password.component';
import { ConfigService } from './../config-service.service';
import {Http, Headers, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

describe('ResetPasswordComponent', () => {
  // let component: ResetPasswordComponent;
  // let fixture: ComponentFixture<ResetPasswordComponent>;

   beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [ResetPasswordComponent, ConfigService, Http, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions]
    });
  });

  // beforeEach(async(() => {
  //   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  //     declarations: [ ResetPasswordComponent ]
  //   })
  //   .compileComponents();
  // }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ResetPasswordComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  // it('should create', () => {
  //   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  // });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect('holaa').toBe('holaa');
  });

  it('Is Password Change Function Working', inject([ResetPasswordComponent], (reset:ResetPasswordComponent) => {
    expect(reset.simplyAFunction()).toBe(true);
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar situation i got when i used HttpHeaders, Hope my experience will help you.
I unit testing always try to mock the services whether it is in build service or written us.

Hence in this case you can mock RequestOptions like this.
 change your providers as

```
providers: [ResetPasswordComponent, ConfigService, Http, ConnectionBackend, { provide: RequestOptions, useValue: RequestOptionsMock }]
```

By doing this in unit testing system will look for mocked RequestOptions rather than original one and hance we can write our own mocked RequestOptions similar providing the properties we have used in our code

A sample mock object could be like this

```
 const RequestOptionsMock = function(){
     return 'mockedResponse';
}
```

Additional note
This is the original RequestOptions from angular documentation https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions

```
class RequestOptions {
constructor(opts: RequestOptionsArgs = {})
method: RequestMethod | string | null
headers: Headers | null
body: any
url: string | null
params: URLSearchParams
search: URLSearchParams
withCredentials: boolean | null
responseType: ResponseContentType | null
merge(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptions
}
```